# Are wired and wireless networks on a router nessassarily one network, when they are not bridged?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I know, that if I bridge the wireless and the wired NIC of my router, that both networks are composed to one. In this case computers from the wireless and the wired LAN can reach each other (they are in the same network).

Is there a possibility to connect both, the wireless and the wired NIC to the WAN without bridging them? I like to give computers in the wireless and the wired LAN access to the internet, but *not* to each other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure: the wireless and wired networks will be separate networks if you do exactly as you suggest: don't bridge them together.

Then you have an additional requirement:

> I like to give computers in the wireless and the wired LAN access to the internet, but not to each other.

You can set firewall rules / filters so that no traffic is allowed to be routed to the wired network which comes from the wireless network, and vice versa.

Traffic continues to be allowed between WAN and wired and also between WAN and wireless.